# Is it possible to combine a list of words in C# like this?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, permutation

Having an array, say `{A, B, C}` I want to create a collections of collections like this

```
Array Input: {A, B, C}
Output:      {A, B, C}, 
             {AB, C}, 
             {A, BC}, 
             {ABC}
```

Or in case of `{A, B, C, D}`

```
Array Input: {A, B, C, D}
Output:      {A, B, C, D}, 
             {AB, C, D}, 
             {ABC, D}, 
             {AB, CD}, 
             {ABCD}, 
             {A, BC, D}, 
             {A, BCD}, 
             {A B CD}
```

I was thinking about making it in C#, but I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Can you code this algorithm?

Comment: What did you try already? Can you share your current code?

Comment: "but I haven't been able to solve it yet". Do you mean you haven't figured out the algorithm in general, or just how to write it in C#?

Comment: Which algorithm did you try in C#? Can you share your current code which does not solve it?

Comment: _"Can you code this algorithm"_ What algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in *general case* you can encode each possible *split* as `0` or `1` (`true` or `false`) to have all the combinations:

```
  A     B     C     D
     ^     ^     ^
  0 or 1  ...  0 or 1
```

For instance:

```
  ABCD    - 000 (no splits)
  A,BCD   - 100 (split, then no splits)
  AB,CD   - 010 (no split, split, no split)
  ABC,D   - 001
  AB,C,D  - 011
  A,B,CD  - 110
  ...
  A,B,C,D - 111 (all splits)
```

**Code:**

```
private static IEnumerable<List<List<T>>> MySolution<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) {
  if (source is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

  var array = source.ToArray();

  if (array.Length <= 0)
    yield break;

  for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << (array.Length - 1); ++mask) {
    List<List<T>> result = new List<List<T>>();

    result.Add(new List<T>() { array[0] });

    for (int index = 0; index < array.Length - 1; ++index) {
      if ((mask & (1 << index)) != 0)
        result.Add(new List<T>() { });

      result[result.Count - 1].Add(array[index + 1]);
    }

    yield return result;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  char[] demo = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

  var result = MySolution(demo)
    .Select(rec => "{" + string.Join(", ", rec
      .Select(item => string.Join("", item))) + "}");

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Output:**

```
{ABCD}
{A, BCD}
{AB, CD}
{A, B, CD}
{ABC, D}
{A, BC, D}
{AB, C, D}
{A, B, C, D}
```

Comment: Your Answer is perfect. You have given me a new approach. thank you so much :)